# How to align ViewGroup to the bottom of the screen

Tags: android, alignment, android-relativelayout, viewgroup, layoutparams

So, I have an activity that is launched as a dialog (Theme.Dialog). I use it to play a video, dimming the background, and looks pretty cool... but it's always centered on the screen and don't know how to move it to the bottom programmatically.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/lr_layout"
            android:background="#FF000000"
            android:padding="0dp" >


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/lr_progressContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FF000000">

    <ProgressBar android:id="@+id/lr_progress"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerInParent="true"
      android:background="@android:color/black"
      style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Large" />

    <View android:id="@+id/disableShape"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:background="#CC000000" 
    />
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And then I add the video player programmatically (View from 3rd party).

I've tried this:

```
layout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.lr_layout);
layout.setY(0);
```

and this:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adViewLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
adViewLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM);
layout.addView(adView, adViewLayoutParams);
```

But the video is still in the center.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting this in your onCreate method.

`WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
lp.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
getWindow().set attributes(lp);`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to align relativeLayout child to be at the bottom, you can set alignParentBottom = true
if you want to align dialog to bottom of screen, you can use popupWindow instead!